# delegate method cannot callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, delegates, notifications

delegate method cannot callback

### This is my .h file

```
@protocol ServiceAPIDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) onRequestLoginFinish:(NSDictionary*) dict;
@end


@interface ServiceAPI : NSObject
+ (id)shareAPI;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ServiceAPIDelegate> delegate_service;
;
@end
```

---

and this is .m file, i use ASIFORMData request and it is callback to requestFinished after get a response from server. but ater that, i want to send data to myviewcontroler use [self.delegate_service onRequestLoginFinish:result]; after this line. my program run normaly not bugs, not callback to function. I cannot see where errors are.

```
 - (void) requestLoginWithUserName:(NSString*) username andPassWord:(NSString*) password {
        NSString* urlString = [PublicInstance API_LOGIN];
        NSArray *keys = PARAMS_ARRAY;
        NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:username, password, [@((int)En) stringValue], APPID, [PublicInstance getDevideID], DEVIDEOS, nil];
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
        NSString* signData = [PublicInstance signData:dict];
        [dict setObject:signData forKey:signKey];

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
        [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

        NSData *jsonDataToPost = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];

        [request appendPostData:jsonDataToPost];

        [request startAsynchronous];
        [request setDelegate:self];
    }

    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {
        NSError* error = [request error];
        if(!error) {
            NSString* responseString = [request responseString];
            NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData;
[self.delegate_service onRequestLoginFinish:result];
}else{
            NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);

        }
    }
```

---

```
ServiceAPI *ShareServiceAPI;

- (id) init {
    if ([self init]) {
        ShareServiceAPI = [ServiceAPI shareAPI];
        ShareServiceAPI.delegate_service =self;
    }
}

- (void) requestLoginWithUserInfor:(UserInfor*) _userinfor {
    [ShareServiceAPI requestLoginWithUserName:_userinfor.username andPassWord:_userinfor.password];
}
```

**#####################**
and this is delegate method - but never callback (O^-oO)

```
- (void) onRequestLoginFinish:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:Key_Status] intValue] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"login successful");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"login fail....");
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me?. Thank you for your time

Comment: did you add delegate in header file?

Comment: thanks for your response, but i added: 
#import "ServiceAPI.h"

@interface LoginView : UIViewController<SDKViewControllerDelegate,FBLoginViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,ServiceAPIDelegate>

Comment: whats does exactly ServiceAPI shareAPI method??

Comment: Check your delegate nil or not before calling requestLoginWithUserName: method

Comment: Can you put a break point in `requestFinished` and see if delegate is `nil` or not ? Just an fyi : ASI is outdated. And this delegate approach to build a service layer will get messy when you have lots of APIs. If you have time switch to a block based approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check if the delegate is nil or not and also check if the delegate responds to the selector as :

```
if(self.delegate_service){
  if([self.delegate_service repondsToSelector:@selector(onRequestLoginFinish:)]){
      [self.delegate_service onRequestLoginFinish:result];
  }
}
```

Through the way you can make your program safe and found the reason that the method is not called.